# COUNT where only two rows

Tags: sql, join, count

```
select DISTINCT po. *
from purchaseorder po
inner join poTask pt on (po.purchaseorderid = pt.purchaseorderid)
inner join poTaskline ptl1 on (pt.potaskid = ptl1.potaskid) and ptl1.poTasklinetype = 'M'
inner join poTaskline ptl2 on (pt.potaskid = ptl2.potaskid) and ptl2.poTasklinetype = 'D'
where po.PoStatus = 6
```

This is giving me all purchase orders that have `Tasklinetypes` of both D and M.

But how do I get it so that it only shows purchase orders that have ONLY a D and an M and no more?

I'm very new and it took me the better half of a day to figure out the above. So I'm REALLY stumped now. I hope you don't need more context than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `(NOT) EXISTS` to check for the presence of those entries in the `poTaskline` table:

```
SELECT po.*
FROM purchaseorder po
INNER JOIN poTask pt ON po.purchaseorderid = pt.purchaseorderid
WHERE po.PoStatus = 6 -- PoStatus of 6
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM poTaskLine ptl WHERE ptl.potaskid = pt.potaskid AND ptl.poTasklinetype = 'M') -- there's a poTaskLine entry for 'M' for this potaskid
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM poTaskLine ptl WHERE ptl.potaskid = pt.potaskid AND ptl.poTasklinetype = 'D') -- there's a poTaskLine entry for 'D' for this potaskid
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM poTaskLine ptl WHERE ptl.potaskid = pt.potaskid AND ptl.poTasklinetype NOT IN ('D', 'M')) -- there aren't any poTaskLine entries for anything else
```

Comment: +1 : Note, however, with three such correlated sub-queries, this ***may*** be slower than a `GROUP BY HAVING` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HAVING` clause to filter your groups.

```
select po. *
from purchaseorder po
inner join poTask pt
  on po.purchaseorderid = pt.purchaseorderid
inner join poTaskline ptl1
  on pt.potaskid = ptl1.potaskid
    and 
      (ptl1.poTasklinetype = 'M'
       OR ptl1.poTasklinetype = 'D')
where po.PoStatus = 6
GROUP BY po.col1, po.col2... -- You must mention here all necessary fields from
                             -- purchaseorder which must be in select list
HAVING COUNT(po.id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following modified query, which uses IN:

```
select DISTINCT po. *
from purchaseorder po
inner join poTask pt on (po.purchaseorderid = pt.purchaseorderid)
inner join poTaskline ptl1 on (pt.potaskid = ptl1.potaskid) and ptl1.poTasklinetype in ('M', 'D')
where po.PoStatus = 6
```

Comment: This will give `Has a 'D' OR has an 'M'`, it doesn't require both, and it doesn't enforce `and no more`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` and compare the values in a `having` clause.  The following fetches all the task information.  It aggregates by the purchase order id:

```
select po.*
from purchaseorder po inner join
     poTask pt
     on (po.purchaseorderid = pt.purchaseorderid) inner join
     poTaskline ptl
     on (pt.potaskid = ptl.potaskid
where po.PoStatus = 6
group by po.purchaseorderid
having sum( ptl.poTasklinetype not in ('D', 'M')) = 0;
```

Finally, the `having` clause counts the number of times where the line type is neither `D` nor `M`.  The `= 0` says that there are no such types.

Comment: Enforces `doesn't have anything that's not 'D' or 'M'` but doesn't enforce `has a 'D' and an 'M'`.

Comment: Interesting syntax. Which RDBMS support this?